how to make the transparent content show in beamer
I am using latex beamer to show the company logo in the top right side of beamer. This is the miminal code I am using:
\documentclass{ctexbeamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\pgfdeclareimage[width=2cm]{companylogo}{figure/logo.png}
\logo{\vspace*{8cm}\pgfuseimage{companylogo}}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{\fontsize{9pt}{14pt}\textbf{sub title}}
\author{jiangxiaoqiang}
\institute{CPU}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}

this is the logo image.

Now I found the picture is transparent png with the logo text. The beamer did not show the logo text. What should I do to make the logo text show in the beamer. I have search the background command but did not found something useful clue.

You can make the white font visible if you change the background colour to something other than white:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\pgfdeclareimage[width=2cm]{companylogo}{O9w6e9w1}
\logo{\vspace*{8cm}\pgfuseimage{companylogo}}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=gray}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\fontsize{9pt}{14pt},series=\bfseries}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{sub title}
\author{jiangxiaoqiang}
\institute{CPU}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}



is it possible to only show the logo text and did not change the whole document.

@Dolphin Modify your logo to either use a background colour or another font colour.
